# Flash swf file accessing error in maven-scala-thymeleaf web project

Tags: scala, maven, flash, thymeleaf

im creating a scala -maven web project for kindergarten kids..
But the problem is when i accessing a image from  resource-image folder i does not show image 
But when i read page with browser it will show the image ..
So is there any solution for showing image while running from jboss

Comment: Not sure I follow. Are you saying if you view the raw resource from the file system locally in a browser you can see the image. But you cannot view the image when accessing it through the application running on jboss? Did I get that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your spring configuration context for the application (in my case its usually a app-context.xml), have you defined the resource mapping? For example, to serve all static content from a root "static" folder:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/static directory -->
<resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>
```

If you are also using spring security (security-context.xml), you'll want to make sure you have excluded "static" similar to:

```
<security:http pattern="/static/**" security="none"/>
```

This should allow you to resolve an image in the application like so:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/myApp/static/img/uglymug.jpg
http://www.somedomain.com/myApp/static/style/uglymug.css
http://www.somedomain.com/myApp/static/script/uglymug.js
```

Comment: There is nothing like 
<security:http pattern="/static/**" security="none"/>
in my security-context.xml file

Comment: well you put this under the thymeleaf label so I just assumed (maybe incorrectly) that this was a spring app. So lets start over... is this a scala app using spring mvc and thymeleaf as a front end? I'm confused now